# Jhipster Blueprint - Override base generators templates

Tags: jhipster

I am developing a jhipster blueprint (base generator 7.8.1) that will have a completely different angular UI with Jhipsters spring-boot backend with customization. I have got the UI part working (using mock backend) and now, I am trying to customize the server sub-generator.

My needs are to be able to modify the base generator templates and also add new templates/files.

Very first use case I am trying to solve is to modify the `SecurityConfiguration_reactive.java.ejs` (basically add more routes). I have tried the following option in the blueprint's `generators/server` sub-generator and it worked,

1. Create an index.js file, delegate all the priorities to the base generator except the  writing priority. The writing phase will basically call the base generators `writeFilesToDisk(serverFiles)` method where the `serverFiles` is from the blueprint.
2. Copy the files.js from the base generator to the blueprint - this is the `serverFiles` from the previous call
3. Copy the template from the base generator (follow the same folder structure) and make the customization

I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52650734/override-file-templates-with-jhipster-blueprint) post that had a better approach but its a little old. So, is there a better way to achieve this?
Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for this?